# Error Crawling Data Twitter With R Programming

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

How do I fix an error like this:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
customer_key<-"-aaaaaa"
customer_secret<-"aaaaaaaa"
access_token<-"212123213-aaaaa"
access_secret<-"ccccccccccccc"
setup_twitter_oauth(customer_key,customer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
Tweets = searchTwitter("anxiety", n=100, lang = "en")
```

> Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘language’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “NULL”)

I User RStudio for run this source code, this is my first time using the twitter API. before I saw the tutorial and they succeeded, after I tried it and there was an error like that. thankyou

Comment: I'd suggest using the [rtweet](https://rtweet.info/) library instead. Authentication is much easier than for `twitteR` and the data structures are more sensible.

Comment: :@neilfws But if you use rtweet, the code that is supposed to be twitteR cannot be used if you use rtweet when crawling data and preprocessing. data obtained if using twitteR there are 19 variables and rtweet there are 90 variables.
can you give me a site to learn to use rtweet.

# I use this for text mining

Answer (score 0):

```
consumer_key <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The steps below are the process of extracting Twitter with keyword #statistics and retrieving 10000 data

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
tw = searchTwitter('#statistics',
                n = 10000,
               retryOnRateLimit = 1617)
```

Make sure the token you use has been updated, and the possibility that the word you will **scrape** is "anxiety" does not exist in the last 7 days. Because scraping using the API will extract data 7 days back only. Suppose I extract data on the 8th, the data that will be pulled is data or sentences containing the word "anxiety" from the 2nd to the 8th.